# Assigning instances to my array (javascript). Whats causing this error?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, instance

I need to assign instances of my object as values in my array, but when I try to add let to my loop for collecting user input, I get an error stating that "[" is an unexpected token. This is a new technique to me so I'm not sure if this is even a practical method for making a table. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
  
  function generateTable() {
    
    var tblStart = "<table>";
    
    //This is the header line for my table.
    var tblMeat = "<tr> <td><b>Name</b></td> <td><b>Attendance</b></td> <td><b>Homework</b></td> <td><b>Midterm</b></td> <td><b>Final</b></td> <td><b>Course Grade</b></td> <td><b>Round Grade</b></td> <td><b>Letter Grade</b></td> </tr>";
    var tblStop = "</table>";
    
    //This determines the number of rows.
    var rowCount = prompt("How many students are in the class?");
    
    //I want to assign instances of Student to this array which will be used to fill the table cells.
    var pupil = [NUMBER(rowCount)];
    
    //This object should process user entries and use them to calculate the total grade, rounded grade, and letter grade.
    function Student(name, attendance, homework, mGrade, fGrade) {
      this.name = name;
      this.attend = attendance;
      this.homewrk = homework;
      this.midter = mGrade;
      this.fingrad = fGrade;
      this.course = function () {
               var attGrade = this.attend * 0.1;
               var hwkGrade = this.homewrk * 0.2;
               var midGrade = this.midter * 0.3;
               var finGrade = this.fingrad * 0.4;
               var combGrade = attGrade + hwkGrade + midGrade + finGrade;
               
               return combGrade.toFixed(2);
               };
      this.round = Math.round(this.course);
      this.letter = function() {
               if(this.course < 60) {
                 return '<p style="color:red;">F</p>';
                 } else if(this.course >= 60 && this.course <= 69.9){
                   return "D";
                   } else if(this.course >= 70 && this.course <= 79.9) {
                     return "C";
                     } else if(this.course >= 80 && this.course <= 89.9) {
                       return "B";
                       } else if(this.course >= 90 && this.course <= 100) {
                         return "A";
                         };
                         };
    }
    
    
    /*This loop should collect user input based on the declared number of students, and assign input values to instances of 
    Student based on which execution of the loop is being run. I am getting an error stating "[" is unexpected for line 79.
    */
    for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
    
      var studentN = prompt("Enter student name.");
      var studentA = prompt("Enter student attendance.");
      var studentH = prompt("Enter student homework grade.");
      var studentM = prompt("Enter student midterm grade.");
      var studentF = prompt("Enter student final grade.");
      
      let pupil[r] = new Student(studentN, studentA, studentH, studentM, studentF);
      
    }
    
    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      
      tblMeat += "<tr>";
      
      for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        
        tblMeat += "<td>" + pupil[i].name + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].attend + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].homewrk + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].midter + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].fingrad + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].course() + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].round + "</td><td>" + pupil[i].letter() + "</td>";
      }
      
      tblMeat += "</tr>";
    }
    
    //This just puts it all together.
    var completeTable = tblStart + tblMeat + tblStop;
    
    document.getElementById("placetable").innerHTML = completeTable;
    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When you get an error the line number is mentioned. It points to the line with the error, which is `let pupil[r] = ......`. That is invalid syntax. `let` is for defining a variable, while `[r]` is for referencing a property/index. You can't do both in one statement. You need to remove the `let`, as in your case you already defined `pupil`.

Comment: I got rid of let and I turned it into a push statement. Now the code runs but it asks for name again after each run of the loop. very confusing.

Comment: I set var pupil = []; and I changed my let line to pupil.push(new Student(studentN, studentA, studentH, studentM, studentF));

Comment: Now in my object this.round is returning NaN.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of problems in your code. I am not really in for an evening of back and forth to make this like a blog on making code work. Maybe you could spend some time on this problem to figure it out yourself? Did you debug and step through the code inspecting the values of your different variables? Hint: `this.course` is a function object. You didn't *call* it.

Comment: I figured it all out! I just needed to realize that my functions couldn't use other functions within the same object to generate output. After that debugging was pretty easy.

Answer (score -1):

I ran your program through [uglifyJS](https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/). It's actually for compressing javascript code, but when there is a lot of code to debug, it's a life changer.

The script told me:

> Parse error: Unexpected token: punc ([)
> Line 59, column 16
> let pupil[r] = new Student(studentN, studentA, studentH, studentM, studentF);

You're trying to define an already existing variable. Remove "let".

A tiny advice for the future.

Comment: Why not use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](https://eslint.org/demo) instead?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, when it fills the same purpose for this question, but it's good that you commented. I wanted to hit three birds with one stone for someone new to javascript.

Comment: Someone new should just use the console.